# A test of preg_match is successful but preg_split fails

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to test a means by which I can break apart a single string containing multiple records about scholarly publications. There is nothing so convenient as a meaningful delimiter separating one record from the next. But I believe it could be accomplished, given the pattern that each record ends with a date followed by a comma and a space (unless no additional records follow, in which case it is merely ended with the date), such as "YYYY-MM-DD, ".

I have begun with a simple test involving a string, and confirming that the regular expression recognizes the pattern I am looking for:

```
$date="2012-09-12, ";
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]), $/",$date))
    {
        echo("yes");
    }else{
        echo("no");
```

However, when I try to take it to the next step by using a sample of real data and preg-split(), the split isn't working. I cannot understand why this simple test, taken from example 1 in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) fails to result in the string being split:

```
<?php
$pubs="L.J. Santodonato, Y. Zhang, M. Feygenson, C.M. Parish, M.C. Gao, R.J. Weber, J.C. Neuefeind, Z. Tang, P.K. Liaw~Deviation from high-entropy configurations in the atomic distributions of a multi-principal-element alloy.~NATURE COMMUNICATIONS~6~2015~~~~0~~0~~2015-11-21, S. Liu, M.C. Gao, P.K. Liaw, Y. Zhang~Microstructures and mechanical properties of AlxCrFeNiTi 0.25 alloys.~JOURNAL OF ALLOYS AND COMPOUNDS~619~2015~610~~~0~~0~~2015-11-21";
$pubsArray = preg_split("/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]), $/", $pubs);
print_r($pubsArray);
?>
```

Data matching the same pattern is found within the example string $pubs, but all I ever get back is an array with a single element containing the full string. I have run out of ideas as to what to try next, and would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: So in case of above string you should get two elements splitted at date ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I believe it could be accomplished, given the pattern that each record ends with a date followed by a comma and a space (unless no additional records follow, in which case it is merely ended with the date), such as "YYYY-MM-DD, ".

As you are trying to split string on occurrence of date for which you can use a simple regex like this `/\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}/`. As you are not validating date, there is no need to match all the months and dates.

To split string at `date` you should use following regex.

**Regex:** `/(?<=\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}),\s*/` looks for occurrence of date followed by optional comma and space and splits on `,[space]` as I suppose you want to keep the date of publication.

**Php Code**

```
<?php
$pubs="L.J. Santodonato, Y. Zhang, M. Feygenson, C.M. Parish, M.C. Gao, R.J. Weber, J.C. Neuefeind, Z. Tang, P.K. Liaw~Deviation from high-entropy configurations in the atomic distributions of a multi-principal-element alloy.~NATURE COMMUNICATIONS~6~2015~~~~0~~0~~2015-11-21, S. Liu, M.C. Gao, P.K. Liaw, Y. Zhang~Microstructures and mechanical properties of AlxCrFeNiTi 0.25 alloys.~JOURNAL OF ALLOYS AND COMPOUNDS~619~2015~610~~~0~~0~~2015-11-21";
$pubsArray = preg_split("/(?<=\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}),\s*/", $pubs);
print_r($pubsArray);
?>
```

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fK3yA3/4)**

**[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/J31L9T)**

Comment: This suggestion does generate the desired outcome. Thank you so much! I also appreciate the link to Regex101. This looks like a very helpful tool.